# VBA to Paste format from original Workbook to new Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I have code below. Essentially what it does is, it opens a dialog box that allows a user to select an excel sheet, then it goes out to the country column (11) filters it, then copies and paste that country into a new workbook names the new workbook after that country then repeats the action for the next country, then it saves and closes each Workbook.

The code works perfectly it just does not copy and paste the original format. I cant seem to be able to get the Special Paste area in the code. I have added pic below to show the difference.

I was just wondering if my code below could be altered to keep the look and formatting of the original

Original Format

[image]

Pasted Format

[image]

MY CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)



    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                       ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the answer is Auto fit the column but I don't know where to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an additional "Template" sheet in the original workbook, which would be formatted as the source sheet. Then you copy the filtered data into the template sheet and copy the template sheet as a new workbook.
The only issue is that if you change the formatting of your source sheet, you would have to do the same in the template sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when I need s small MACRO to do something I hesitate how to implement, I use the MACRO RECORDING feature of Excel. In your case, I would start the recording, go to the source sheet, select and copy the range, go to the target sheet, click on the cell into which the PASTE should start, Paste, Stop recording.

Then, while in developer mode, you will find the generated macro which you can update to fully comply with your needs.

This method ALWAYS worked for me. Hope it does so for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this piece of code and plugged it in just before the save and close and its working fine

```
Columns("A:B").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

The place where it goes

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                     Columns("A:Y").Select
                  Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
```